# Problem with square brackets in tabularray

Tags: tabularray

I run into trouble with this example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tblr}{ccc} \hline 
        m & mG & Weight \\ \hline 
        [0, 0, 0] & [0, 0, 0, 0] & 0 \\ \hline 
        [0, 0, 1] & [1, 0, 1, 1] & 3 \\ \hline 
        [0, 1, 0] & [0, 1, 0, 1] & 2 \\ \hline 
        [0, 1, 1] & [1, 1, 1, 0] & 3 \\ \hline 
        [1, 0, 0] & [1, 0, 0, 1] & 2 \\ \hline 
        [1, 0, 1] & [0, 0, 1, 0] & 1 \\ \hline 
        [1, 1, 0] & [1, 1, 0, 0] & 2 \\ \hline 
        [1, 1, 1] & [0, 1, 1, 1] & 3 \\ \hline 
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

I get the error message "Illegal unit of measure(pt inserted)". I suspect that the square brackets used is the culprit, but I can't find a workaround in the documentation. The example compiles fine with round brackets instead of square brackets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`tabulararray`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabulararray) redefines `\hline` to take an optional argument (specifying the width of the rule that is inserted). With square brackets in the first column, you need to note that it's not part of the optional argument using something like `\relax`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{ccc}
  \hline 
  m & mG & Weight \\
  \hline\relax 
  [0, 0, 0] & [0, 0, 0, 0] & 0 \\
  \hline\relax
  [0, 0, 1] & [1, 0, 1, 1] & 3 \\
  \hline\relax 
  [0, 1, 0] & [0, 1, 0, 1] & 2 \\
  \hline\relax 
  [0, 1, 1] & [1, 1, 1, 0] & 3 \\
  \hline\relax 
  [1, 0, 0] & [1, 0, 0, 1] & 2 \\
  \hline\relax 
  [1, 0, 1] & [0, 0, 1, 0] & 1 \\
  \hline\relax 
  [1, 1, 0] & [1, 1, 0, 0] & 2 \\
  \hline\relax 
  [1, 1, 1] & [0, 1, 1, 1] & 3 \\
  \hline 
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Don't think there is a need for the multitude of `\hline`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{ccc}
  \hline[0.08em]% Similar to \toprule of booktabs
  m & mG & Weight \\
  \hline\relax 
  [0, 0, 0] & [0, 0, 0, 0] & 0 \\\relax
  [0, 0, 1] & [1, 0, 1, 1] & 3 \\\relax 
  [0, 1, 0] & [0, 1, 0, 1] & 2 \\\relax 
  [0, 1, 1] & [1, 1, 1, 0] & 3 \\\relax 
  [1, 0, 0] & [1, 0, 0, 1] & 2 \\\relax 
  [1, 0, 1] & [0, 0, 1, 0] & 1 \\\relax 
  [1, 1, 0] & [1, 1, 0, 0] & 2 \\\relax 
  [1, 1, 1] & [0, 1, 1, 1] & 3 \\
  \hline[0.08em]
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, you can just use hlines as an option in tblr environment

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution is to put `[]` after `\hline` if the following row starts with `[`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tblr}{ccc} \hline 
        m & mG & Weight \\ \hline[] 
        [0, 0, 0] & [0, 0, 0, 0] & 0 \\ \hline[] 
        [0, 0, 1] & [1, 0, 1, 1] & 3 \\ \hline[] 
        [0, 1, 0] & [0, 1, 0, 1] & 2 \\ \hline[] 
        [0, 1, 1] & [1, 1, 1, 0] & 3 \\ \hline[] 
        [1, 0, 0] & [1, 0, 0, 1] & 2 \\ \hline[] 
        [1, 0, 1] & [0, 0, 1, 0] & 1 \\ \hline[] 
        [1, 1, 0] & [1, 1, 0, 0] & 2 \\ \hline[] 
        [1, 1, 1] & [0, 1, 1, 1] & 3 \\ \hline
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]